# Clicking the company pages tab loses location filter

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On the page at
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/location/houston%2c%20tx%2c%20united%20states?a=x0VW the company pages tab shows "2 company pages", but when I click the tab, the filter apparently goes away and it shows "731 company pages".  The number of jobs on the jobs tab also increases.

Comment: We just deployed the fix, thx for reporting!

Comment: Someone get @mythz enough rep to not have to wait for the edit queue!